# What does "link: false" mean in my Brewfile?

Tags: homebrew, python

My `Brewfile` created with `brew bundle dump` contains one line with `link: false`:

```
...
brew "git"
brew "python@3.8", link: false
brew "glib"
...
```

I don't see any kind of `--link` option for the `brew install` command, so I don't think it's a record of some install option for `python@3.8`. The only potentially relevant thing about it I see in either the `brew` and `homebrew-bundle` documentation is the `brew link` command, which I have not used.

And as far as I can tell, the `python3.8` command is installed and works the same as any of the other packages listed in the `Brewfile`.

Comment: Did you check the documentation on https://brew.sh/ ?

Comment: yes and as noted I didn't see anything helpful there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `link:false` in the `Brewfile` appears to skip linking the installed binary in `/usr/local/Cellar/...` into `/usr/local/bin` (and thus my user `$PATH`) during bulk installation with `brew bundle install`.

I am guessing since `python@3.8` was installed both as a dependency for something else (and thus not linked?) and it was also installed manually, it somehow erroneously was being output in the `Brewfile` as `link: false` though it should not have been.

Getting `brew bundle dump` to stop outputting the `link: false` was accomplished by forcibly uninstalling and reinstalling:

```
$ brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python@3.8
$ brew install python@3.8
$ brew bundle dump
```